# Playing a sound with Swipe Gesture on ViewController in Swift 4

Tags: swift, audio, gesture

I need to know, how I can add a wav sound (page flipping) to a viewController when a Swipe Gesture is activated. I have 5 different View Contrllers, and when the child swipes the gesture, I would like it to make play a file sound (page flipping). I already implemented the Swipe Gestures on all viewControllers (LEFT & RIGHT), but need the sound to go along with the Gesture.

Comment: What's the hard part? If you already know how to respond when the swipe gesture occurs, why can't you play the sound as part of that response?

Comment: I did the Gestures in Xcode (not in coding). The gestures are attached to the whole viewController not to a button.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer

Comment: Thank you @meggar , I've found the AvAudio  sound part. And can attach the sound to a button, but I don't know how to attach it to Gesture.

Comment: @matt, I think mikeT is trying to say he did it in Storyboards and is asking how to get a reference to that swipe gesture in code so that he can play the sound in the appropriate part.

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it.  Add the gesture recognizer to the view in code and setup an action for it to call with each swipe.  Get the direction in the function in case you want different sounds or behavior.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
}

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:

            // Play sound here

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:

            // Play sound here

            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```